# Setting CSS properties through Javascript if/else statements using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a button in a website right now that will adjust the size of a toolbar based on the visibility of two other columns. So far I've written the following, but as soon as I add if/else statements into the mix, the Javascript will not execute.

Here's my code thus far:

```
<script>
        $("#categorizedBlogsToggle_button").click(function() {
            if ($("#uncategorizedBlogsContainerDiv".css("display") == "none")){
            $("#categorizedBlogsContainerDiv").toggle( "fast", function() {
            });
                $("#blogToolbar").css({
                    "width": "82%",
                    "left": "5%"
                });
        }
            else{
                $("#categorizedBlogsContainerDiv").toggle( "fast", function() {
                });
                $("#blogToolbar").css({
                    "width": "70%",
                    "left": "20%"
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Thank you!

Edit: Updated with jQuery selector and fixed brackets, but it still isn't working for me.

I'm not sure if it would affect the syntax I'd use, but the attributes I'm trying to modify in these elements are derived from an external style sheet. (In this case /blog.css)

Comment: This code should work.

Comment: not quite there yet, should be `$("#uncategorizedBlogsContainerDiv").css`

Comment: I think I fixed that with my edit, also added the ( ) brackets for an if statement so it looks like  
`if ($("#uncategorizedBlogsContainerDiv".css("display") == "none")){`

Comment: I still think you have a bracket wrong, should be `($("#uncategorizedBlogsContainerDiv").css("display") == "none"){` See http://jsfiddle.net/k6Gp6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            if ("#uncategorizedBlogsContainerDiv".css("display") == "none"){
```

Should read:

```
            if ($("#uncategorizedBlogsContainerDiv").css("display") == "none"){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jquery selector:

```
if ($("#uncategorizedBlogsContainerDiv").css...
```

Comment: Youu mean missing braces? ;)